# iOS HTML checkbox screen blocked if keyboard is shown

Tags: html, ios, checkbox, uiwebview

I have an iOS application which views URL inside UIWebView. There is a form in this URL with two text input fields and one checkbox.

When the cursor is inside one of the text input fields and the keyboard is shown, then I check the checkbox, the screen becomes semi-black and the form dialog is removed. But when I check the checkbox normally - without the keyboard showing -, it works fine and no error happens.

Here is the form code:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('account/login');?>" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
                        <!-- Form Group -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <!-- Label -->
                            <label for="user" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo lang_key('email'); ?></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <!-- Input -->
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="useremail" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key('email'); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="password" class="col-sm-3 control-label"><?php echo lang_key('password'); ?></label>
                            <div class="col-sm-9">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control"  name="password" placeholder="<?php echo lang_key('password'); ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> <?php echo lang_key('remember_me'); ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                                <!-- Button -->
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-red"><?php echo lang_key('login'); ?></button>&nbsp;
                                <button type="submit" formaction="<?php echo site_url('account/signup');?>" class="btn btn-white"><?php echo lang_key('sign_up'); ?></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

The 'remember_me' checkbox is the one which causes the issue if the keyboard is shown when it is checked

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard delegates are what you are looking for.

Use the keyboard Will Show delegate to push the UIWebview up, and Use the keyboard will hide delegate to return push the UIWebview down.

Hope this helps!